# Разметка Open Graph VK на сайт?

Tags: opengraph

Скажите пожалуйста как сделать, чтоб при нажатии кнопки поделиться в соц сети ВК, вместо картинки, было видео на весь экран. Разметка Open Graph
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Например если нажать поделиться на ютубе, то на страницу в ВК идет именно видео

Comment: Есть пример страницы для которой видео показывается?

Comment: вот например https://mddl31.com/video/bodybuilding/862-idealnaya-myshechnaya-devochka.html

Comment: Не показывается.